# Django sort query by related model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to sort a query set based on a related model in a django function view.

My models are:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.full_name)

class Instrument(models.Model):
    instrument_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.instrument_name

class Member(models.Model):
    musician = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.musician)

class Role(models.Model):
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.member) +   ' | ' + str( self.instrument)

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_name + ' | ' + str( self.band)
```

My function looks something like this (passing the album id into the function):

```
def album_view(request, alb_id):
    album = Album.objects.get(id= alb_id)
    band = album.band
    allroles = album.role.all()
    context = {
        'band' : band,
        'album' : album,
        'artists' : allroles,
    return render(request,'bandapp/album_view.html', context)
```

`allroles` is the query I am having issues with.
It returns the Role objects (as expected), however, this list is difficult to iterate over in the template.
I essentially want to end up with (within the template)
Artist One | Guitar,
Artist One | Vocals,
Artist Two | Drums,
Artist Three | Bass,
Artist Three | Percussion

But as I cannot sort `allroles` by musician, I cannot iterate over them properly as they are in order of creation.
Which may result with:
Artist One | Guitar,
Artist Three | Bass,
Artist Two | Drums,
Artist Three | Percussion,
Artist One | Vocals

The relationship is
Album ->Roles ->Members -> Musicians
(Members will be used in forms to dictate if they could be chosen as worked on an album by band id)..

Ultimately, I would like it to display on the page as Artist One (Guitar, Vocals), Artist Two (Drums), Artist Three (Bass, Percussion)

Any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot quite get my head around it enough to make it work. All other aspects work without any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there should be any problem using order by in a foreign key relation.

```
allroles = album.role.all().order_by('member__musician__full_name')
```

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't want it to be sorted alphabetically, e.g. he wants `1. Guitar -> 2. Vocals -> Drums -> Bass -> Percussion`.

Comment: Sry, but I still don't understand completely, is there any specific order he wants?? or does he wants to group instruments acc to musicians, 
acc to example .
```Artist One | Guitar, Artist One | Vocals, Artist Two | Drums, Artist Three | Bass, Artist Three | Percussion```
here he can order by multiple columns also.
```order_by('member__musician__full_name', 'instrument __instrument_name ')```

Comment: @neeraj9194 Thank you so much!!
I couldn't work out where to put the dunders, that worked brilliantly!!

Thanks for your help (1st year CS student here) :)